# Como alterar o prefixo e o nome de um atributo em uma tag XML em uma NFS-e?

Tags: c#, xml, serialização

Olá, sou iniciante em desenvolvimento de NFS-e  e não estou conseguindo alterar o prefixo e o nome do atributo abaixo, coloquei no código para que fosse xsi, porém independente do que eu coloque ele gera o xml com d1p1. Como substituir este d1p1 por xsi nas suas duas ocorrências?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EnviarLoteRpsEnvio xmlns="http://isscuritiba.curitiba.pr.gov.br/iss/nfse.xsd" xmlns:d1p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" d1p1:schemaLocation="http://isscuritiba.curitiba.pr.gov.br/iss/nfse.xsd">
<LoteRps Id="lote6014" versao="2.0">
      <NumeroLote>6014</NumeroLote>
      <Cnpj>0000000000</Cnpj>
      <InscricaoMunicipal>55114444</InscricaoMunicipal>
      <QuantidadeRps>1</QuantidadeRps>
      <ListaRps>
         <Rps>
```

Abaixo o código utilizado para gerar os atributos em C#:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace NFSE.Net.Layouts.CuritibaPr {
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("EnviarLoteRpsEnvio", Namespace = "http://isscuritiba.curitiba.pr.gov.br/iss/nfse.xsd")]

public class EnviarLoteRpsEnvio
{
    public XmlSerializerNamespaces GetAdditionalNamespaces()
    {
        XmlSerializerNamespaces names = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        names.Add("", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        names.Add("xsi", "http://isscuritiba.curitiba.pr.gov.br/iss/nfse.xsd");
        return names;
    }

       [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "schemaLocation", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
       public string XSDSchemaLocation
       {
           get
           {
               return "http://isscuritiba.curitiba.pr.gov.br/iss/nfse.xsd";
           }     
           set
           { }
       }
```

Obrigado.